# How to override BasicAuthenticationFilter using the schema configuration?

Tags: spring-security

We use Spring Security 4.x and I want to override `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.
Unfortunately I was not able to find how to configure the class name for the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` nor in the `http` element neither in the `http-basic` element the schema configuration.

How to override `BasicAuthenticationFilter` using the schema configuration?

I have tried to override `BasicAuthenticationFilter` using the custom filter without success – the schema continue to create the default `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.

**Added**

Very strange. I configured `auto-config="false` but I still can see the creation of the default `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.

It should not be created according to the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http

**Added**

The configuration w/o beans definitions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


    <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <!-- AspectJ pointcut expression that locates our "post" method and applies security that way
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* bigbank.*Service.post*(..))" access="ROLE_TELLER"/>
        -->
    </sec:global-method-security>

    <sec:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" pattern="/api/**"  disable-url-rewriting="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:custom-filter ref="rememberUrlFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <sec:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="ssoFilter" />

        <sec:intercept-url  pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <sec:logout logout-url="/logout.faces" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandlerImpl" />
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <sec:headers disabled="true"/>
        <!--<sec:custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>-->

        <sec:custom-filter ref="localhostIntegrationFilter" after="ANONYMOUS_FILTER"/>
        <sec:access-denied-handler  ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    </sec:http>

    <bean class="org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter" name="fileUploadFilter"/>

    <sec:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="false">
        <sec:custom-filter ref="fileUploadFilter" before="FIRST"/>
        <sec:custom-filter ref="rememberUrlFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <sec:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="ssoFilter" />

        <sec:intercept-url  pattern="/pages/**" access="isAuthenticated()"  />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.faces" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <sec:headers disabled="true"/>

        <sec:form-login login-page="/login.faces"
                        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                        authentication-failure-url="/login.faces"
                        default-target-url="/pages/defaultPage.faces"
                        username-parameter="j_username"
                        password-parameter="j_password"
                        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"
        />

        <sec:logout logout-url="/logout.faces"
                    success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandlerImpl"
                />

        <sec:custom-filter ref="localhostIntegrationFilter" after="ANONYMOUS_FILTER"/>
        <sec:access-denied-handler  ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    </sec:http>

...

</beans>
```

Comment: Please share your spring xml

Comment: I have added the configurations without beans definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the schema documentation in the [xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd) if you want to replace a filter you need to use the position tag:

```
<sec:custom-filter ref="customBasicAuth" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
```

Also if you include the `<sec:http-basic` element, then the default basic auth filter will be added to the filter chain.

The `auto-config` is a legacy attribute and can be removed (no need to set it to false)

Comment: Thanks, remove of the `auto-config` did the work!
Do you know what should I add in addition when i set the `auto-config`  to false (by its remove)?
I do not need `form-login` in the current element and i do have `logout`.
 What I can add to be in the same functionality as  `auto-config=true`?
Not sure here the full answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609655/what-is-the-use-of-auto-config-true-in-spring-security

Comment: The linked answer is correct. The same thing is mentioned in the xsd about auto-config "A legacy attribute which automatically registers a login form, BASIC authentication and a logout URL and logout services.". Logout services in this case are the filters which handle logout.

Comment: Thank, your help worth a bounty :)